# How to run .sql script against docker container after a different (dependent) container starts?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I have a SpringBoot application container `myApi` that depends on another SpringBoot application container `configApi`, they both use flyway. They also both depend on a `postgres` container. `configApi` exposes an endpoint that `myApi` uses to fetch all relevant configs (db details etc).

What currently happens is:

1. `postgres` container starts and inits appropriate db's and user
2. `configApi` container starts
   a) it connects to `postgres`
   b) it runs a flyway migration (creates required schema and tables)
   c) api launches and is ready
3. `myApi` container starts
   a) it hits a config endpoint exposed by `configApi`
   b) the request fails because `configApi` cannot find any useful data in `postgres` since none was inserted

My restrictions are:

- I cannot modify `configApi` code to contain anything specific to `myApi` or an environment
- Flyway migration during `configApi` launch is what creates the tables that would contain any required data
- I cannot create the tables and populate them when `postgres` is launched (using `init.sql`) because then `configApi` flyway migration will fail
- `myApi` cannot contain any hard coded or environmental info about `postgres` since it's all supposed to be fetched from `configApi` endpoints

### Problem summary TLDR:

How do I execute a sql script against the `postgres` container after `configApi` has launched but before `myApi` has launched without modifying `configApi` or `myApi` to contain anything specific to each other's environments?

I have the following docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: "3"

volumes:
  db_data:

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.14
    volumes:
      - ./init-local.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  configApi:
    image: org/config-api:latest
    ports:
      - 8234:8234
    environment:
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_HOST=postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  myApi:
    build: ./my-api
    image: org/my-api:latest
    container_name: my-api
    ports:
     - 9080:9080
    environment:
     - CONFIG_MANAGER_API_URL=http://configApi:8234/
    depends_on:
     - postgres
     - configApi
```

Notes (I'll be adding more as questions come in):

- I am using a single postgres container because this is for local/test, both api's use unique db's within that postgres instance

Comment: One solution I've seen in the past is to create a lightweight, self terminating app that will launch between `configApi` and `myApi` just for data loading, I don't like this solution. It's too much maintenance overhead.

Comment: That application can be Flyway itself, it is available as a docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/flyway/flyway . I have used it to build up a full local development database. You could use it to insert data only. Not sure if that will work for you though, I am kind of lost in your mountain of restrictions. I would rather break the restrictions than work around them to be honest, the most sense is to insert the data as part of the config API setup.

Comment: @Gimby Thanks, I'll have a look. The restrictions come from the configApi being a generic app, I can't modify it to contain product specific configs. That'd ruin the whole point of it being generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's my solution.

I modified my flyway code to dynamically include extra scripts if they exists as follows.

In my database java config in `configApi` I read an env variable that specifies any dir with extra/app external scripts:

```java
// on class level
@Value("${FLYWAY_FOLDER}")
private String externalFlywayFolder;

//when creating DataSource bean
List<String> flywayFolders = new ArrayList<>();
flywayFolders.add("classpath:db/migrations");
if (externalFlywayFolder != null && !externalFlywayFolder.isEmpty()) {
    flywayFolders.add("filesystem:"+externalFlywayFolder);
}
String[] flywayFoldersArray = new String[flywayFolders.size()];
flywayFolders.toArray(flywayFoldersArray);

Flyway flyway = Flyway
        .configure()
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .baselineOnMigrate(true)
        .schemas("flyway")
        .mixed(true)
        .locations(flywayFoldersArray)
        .load();
flyway.migrate();
```

Then I modified the docker compose to attach extra files to the container and set the `FLYWAY_FOLDER` env variable:

```yaml
  configApi:
    image: org/config-api:latest
    volumes:
      - ./scripts/flyway/configApi:/flyway #attach scripts to container
    ports:
      - 8234:8234
    environment:
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_HOST=postgres
      - FLYWAY_FOLDER=flyway #specify script dir for api
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Then just a case of adding the files, but the trick is to make them [repeatable migrations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/tutorials/repeatable.html) so they don't interfere with any versioned migrations that may be done for the configApi itself.

Repeatable migrations are applied after versioned migrations, also they get reapplied if their checksum changes.